# Run jquery function when specific option is selected from dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with a dropdown that has values 0-4, when value 2 is selected, I need some simple jquery to run which disables a summernote text input box. If the selection is then changed again away from 2, I need for jquery to run to re-enable the box. Whats the best way to go about this?

```
      <select>
            <option value="0">No selection</option>
            <option value="1">selection 1</option>
            <option value="2">selection 2 (disable textarea)</option>
            <option value="3">selection 3</option>
            <option value="4">selection 4</option>                                   
      </select>
```

the jquery to disable the box:

```
     $('.note-editable').attr({contenteditable: 'false'});
```

I am not sure how to handle events when dealing with a select box and targeting specific options ?

Comment: $("input").focus() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you need

```
$('select').on("change",function(){
      if($(this).val()==2)
           $('.note-editable').attr({contenteditable: 'false'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
    var note = $('.note-editable');
    if($(this).val() == "2"){
      note.attr({contenteditable: 'false'});
    } else {
      note.attr({contenteditable: 'true'});
    }
})
```